# Python socket sending old data

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess

I'm having a hard time in Python with *subprocess* and the *socket* module. What's happening is, I'm sending the command to the client, but it doesn't send back anything. Until, I send another command, and I get the output of the previous. I've tried all the buffer sizes and none work.

**SERVER:**

```
while True:
    shell = input(">> ")
    conn.send(shell.encode())
    data = conn.recv(1600)
    print(data.decode())
```

**CLIENT:**

```
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1600)
    if not data: break
    data = data.decode()
    commd = subprocess.Popen(data, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    out, err = commd.communicate()
    sock.send(out)
print("Exiting because no data")
```

Comment: use `print()` to see which line is executed and what you get in variables. It is called "print debuging".

Comment: create minimal working code with your problem. And then we can run it and see it. And then we can test modifications.

Comment: socket is low level network object so it is very primitive and maybe you should create something more complex - protocol  - which first send ie. 4 bytes with length of string in `shell` and then client recevie 4 bytes and it knows how big value use in next `recv()` to get `shell`

Comment: or you can do like in HTTP protocol - send `new line` at the end of `shell` and client should use loop with `recv(1)` until it get `new line`